# Can I get Jquery Pulsate Effect without using Jquery UI?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have in a situation where I cannot use Jquery UI for a reason. I am trying to do get Jquery UI Pulsate Effect without using Jquery UI. Similar to this link, http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate. I have search a lot but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Why can't you use it? Just take the relevant parts out of it

Comment: Have you thought about using CSS3? Not sure on your browser support requirements but you can create effects like this quite easily. Have a look here http://daneden.me/animate/ for some inspiration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know what original UI code looks like, but this is super simple implementation using animate function:

```
$.fn.pulse = function(options) {

    var options = $.extend({
        times: 3,
        duration: 1000
    }, options);

    var period = function(callback) {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, options.duration, function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, options.duration, callback);
        });
    };
    return this.each(function() {
        var i = +options.times, self = this,
        repeat = function() { --i && period.call(self, repeat) };
        period.call(this, repeat);
    });
};

$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).pulse({times: 4, duration: 500});
});
```

Check the demo below or this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/4HUjn/1/).

```js
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).stop().pulse({times: 4, duration: 300});
});

$.fn.pulse = function(options) {
    
    var options = $.extend({
        times: 3,
        duration: 1000
    }, options);
    
    var period = function(callback) {
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, options.duration, function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, options.duration, callback);
        });
    };
    return this.each(function() {
        var i = +options.times, self = this,
        repeat = function() { --i && period.call(self, repeat) };
        period.call(this, repeat);
    });
};
```

```css
div {background-color: green; padding: 20px; display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click me</div>
```

Comment: Sure: `$('div').pulse({times: 4, duration: 500});`

Answer (score 3):

you could copy the source of the jquery pulsate effect and add that to your project.

But whats the point, if you can add that file to your project, why not just add the original jquery ui pulsate file.

You don't have to downlaod the whole of jquery-ui, just the parts you want : http://jqueryui.com/download/.

Comment: I have lot of low memory mobile clients.

Comment: @user960567 you don't have to downlaod the whole of jquery, just the parts you want

Answer (score 3):

There is a standalone jquery plugin for the pulsate effect here:

https://github.com/jsoverson/jquery.pulse.js