# CSS transition to smooth transition of elements after another element is hidden.

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-animations

Issue: Can I use a CSS transition to control how a div moves into vacated space created by another div being hidden.

I have elements in my app that appear and disappear (display: none) based on user set intervals. As expected with display:none, sometimes an adjacent element  will move to occupy the space vacated by .

I don't mind that  moves in this case. I would like to control *how* it moves. What I would like is for  to move via a css transition or other method and not just jerk into place. Is this possible?

Here's a JS fiddle that illustrates the scenario via button click. When #red is hidden I would like to see #blue move into position more gradually. Thx.

http://jsfiddle.net/uV6W7/1/

Here's the code in the jsfiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<p>
<button id="remove" type="button">Remove Red</button>
```

**CSS**

```
#red {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#blue {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#remove").on("click", function(event){
    if($('#remove').text()=="Remove Red") {
      $('#red').fadeOut();
      $('#remove').html("Restore Red");
    }else {
      $('#red').fadeIn();
      $('#remove').html("Remove Red");
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you look into jQuery Effects? http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Comment: Also, http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to avoid adding jquery UI as I understand it doesn't get along too well with Bootstrap. Was hoping there was a CSS only solution.

Comment: You can do it without jQuery UI. Try checking this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14934336/can-i-get-jquery-pulsate-effect-without-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hide red by sliding it to a 0 width state. This would cause the right element to seem to slide into the place of the left.

`$('#red').animate({width:'toggle'});` Can be used to slide it to the left.

You can also wrap `#red` in another div and then fade `#red` and afterwards slide the container to combine the visual effects.

Comment: That is an interesting idea, I will investigate. But the element being removed might be to the left, it might be above, so that could get complicated to manage. 
It's likely that I'm hoping for too easy of a solution. :)

Comment: Well you can also use the jquery slideUp()/slideDown() methods. For vertical solutions. Sadly I don't know of a magic universal option that works for every direction.

Comment: I have to play with it but something along these lines might actually work for me. when I say it's "above" it's not really, it's just wrapped to the next line, so a variation on this theme might help smooth it out. I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.